# When viewing a Visual Studio Git commit, how to open the local copy of a file?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When viewing a Git commit in Visual Studio (I'm currently using 2017), many times per day I wish to open the local copy of a file that was edited in a commit, but there isn't a built in option (that I know of) that can do this. Here are the available options when viewing a commit:

[image]

Note that the "Open" option opens a read-only copy of the file as it looked in the commit. I would like to open the current version of that file in my checked out branch (usually so I can make edits based on PR suggestions). Today what I do is: switch over to Solution Explorer, type the filename into the search box, wait for it to find it, and then open the file. But this is slow and cumbersome to do hundreds of times per day. I'm thinking there should be another option next to "Open" like "Open Local Copy".

Is there a way to do this in VS, or using an existing plugin?

Comment: Nowadays I typically have VS Code open with the Git Graph extension, specifically for this reason. I also like that Git Graph can show multiple branches in the same graph, and that clicking on a merge commit shows the diff I always wish to see, which is `git diff @~1 @`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be any native feature/plugin which would open that file when done through the Team Explorer / commit details.

Searching for said file would be the current workaround. But [suggesting an enhancement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/suggest-a-feature?view=vs-2019) is always an option.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if it it's possible to create a normal VS plugin to hook into that drop down (in the Git Commit window) to include this feature, or would it have to be native to VS? When I look at tutorials and examples of what you can do with VSIX, I'm not finding any examples like this.

Comment: @TTT I haven't found any example either.